# Oracle does not use index on date time column

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, oracle19c

In my spring-boot application querying on `LocalDateTime` field of entity can not use index in Oracle.

I have two different `DATE` typed columns om my table. In application one column's type is `LocalDate` and the other is `LocalDateTime`. While querying database with `LocalDate` column, the query runs fast as expected. But when i use `LocalDateTime` field as query object the query slows down and can not returns result in timeout time. Both `DATE` columns has its own indexes seperately.

Should I change some default settings of Hibernate or update some configs in Oracla database to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share the SQL that is being executed, as well as the DDL for the table and the indexes.

Comment: explainplans for the two queries would also be useful. there are a variety of reasons that the optimizer may choose to use or not use particular indexes.

Comment: Hibernate may compose a crazy select statement. You need to find out the statement (for example Oracle Session Browser in TOAD) then yiu can check.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements for your table; the `SELECT` statements that hibernate generates; the `EXPLAIN PLAN` for those `SELECT` statements. Without details of the query and the explain plan the question is impossible to answer.